# Binding to global variables in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, comet

I am fairly new to Polymer, and only just studied how data binding works. I am porting an existing Dojo application, where there would be:

1) A single store (holding data) for each URL

2) A message from the server when a store element was updated

As a result, a dynamically made select box which depended on data in the store would automagically have an extra item if anywhere in the application a user added an item to the store (which held the data)

I am trying to replicate something like this in Polymer.

Use case: imagine an URL like this: `/app/categories`. By querying it with an HTTP GET, you end up with a JSON of all the categories available. While the app is running, the server might notify of a new element in /app/categories. as a result, all of the selects in the application would then have the extra item automagically.

In Polymer, I learned how to bind a property *in the current element* to a property *in a contained element*. I understand how this happens with the right events being fired etc. So, the idea would be to create a select where the items are generated by a `dom-repeat`, which would be bound to... a somehow global variable (?).

But... is it even possible to bind the property of a contained element to a "global" variable, rather than a property of the containing element?

OR, more broadly, is there a pattern (or even an established pattern) to make sure that when a global variable is changed (thanks to a comet message, or whatever), a bunch of elements binding to it will be notified and therefore changed (in this case, the "select" using dom-repeat to show the items!)

Here is a [JSBin that shows how to create a menu via `iron-ajax`](http://jsbin.com/xuyoki/edit?html,output) At this point what's missing to the JSBin is the simulation of a server push about a data change, as well as a way to have all of the menus update at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the most sane and maintainable pattern is a one way data flow approach (something along the lines of [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) or [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) (which is a bit simpler).

There is one global state object that exists as as a graph structure and the data flows down your component tree (starting with the root component).
Each component has well defined input properties and receives data from the parent component (using data-binding) and passes on parts of the data to its children. When a component changes state, it fires an event which bubbles up the component tree up to your root component that can then update your global state object (which again flows down your component tree), communicate with the backend, etc.

I can also recommend this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLNYkxOF6rcICdISJclfQhj2S8QZGjXV8J&v=ZDjiUmx51y8) from the Polymer 2015 summit, which explains a similar approach (mediator pattern).

Comment: I highly recommend using Redux. I'm coming from Angular 2, but I've been using Redux successfully. I'm now beginning to use Redux in Polymer projects. It makes things easy to reason about, and because of the declarative nature of web components, a lot of functionality can be abstracted away into custom elements that you pop in when you need. It makes things declarative and...nice. I've been working on a custom element that makes working with Redux in Polymer projects simple: https://github.com/lastmjs/polymer-redux-store

Comment: @lastmjs: Yeah I have also started to use Redux together with Polymer and it works really good. I am using this library tough (https://github.com/tur-nr/polymer-redux). It exposes the store via behaviors.

Comment: @Ümit I'm trying to stay away from behaviors, because they are specific to Polymer and not standard in the platform. I believe they start to unnecessarily couple you to Polymer instead of web components, which is why I suggest using a custom element for Redux.

Comment: IMHO state management is orthogonal to web-components and the web platform. For me web-components is just a view layer similar to react. Although Polymer allows you to create non UI elements, its main purpose are UI elements. I don't think it makes sense to wrap in `Redux` in a custom element, because `Redux` is concerned about the global state.